# Doctrine Migration Rollback in Laravel Integration Test

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I am trying to roll back all migrations at the end of any feature test, to reset the database. This is my current code:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    Artisan::call('doctrine:migrations:migrate');
}

/**
 * Rollback the database migrations so tests are idempotent.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function tearDown()
{
    Artisan::call(
        'doctrine:migrations:rollback', [
            '0'
        ]
    );
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

The setup works fine, but the teardown only rolls back a single migration. I have also tried:

`doctrine:migrations:migrate first`

Which works on the command line, but not in the feature tests.

Any ideas?

Comment: witch verssion of Laravel do you use ?

Comment: we're using version 5.4

Comment: so you can just use the trait `DatabaseMigrations` as the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) says `rollback the database after each test and migrate it before the next test. Laravel provides a simple DatabaseMigrations trait that will automatically handle this for you. Simply use the trait on your test class and everything will be handled for you`

Comment: That works with Eloquent, not Doctrine, I think

Comment: While they don't say it in the doc i think it will work even for Doctrine, give it a try and see

Comment: Afraid I have already tried to use this trait :-(